# Why does brew has to compile files instead of simply installing binaries

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, homebrew

I simply did a `brew upgrade` and ended up with the following:

```
==> Reinstalling pyside
Warning: Your Xcode (12.3) is outdated.
Please update to Xcode 13.2.1 (or delete it).
Xcode can be updated from the App Store.

==> Installing dependencies for pyside: ninja and llvm
==> Installing pyside dependency: ninja
==> Pouring ninja--1.11.1.big_sur.bottle.tar.gz
  /usr/local/Cellar/ninja/1.11.1: 10 files, 453.2KB
==> Installing pyside dependency: llvm
==> Pouring llvm--15.0.6.big_sur.bottle.tar.gz
  /usr/local/Cellar/llvm/15.0.6: 6,411 files, 1.3GB
==> Installing pyside
==> cmake -S . -B build -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=clang++ -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/usr/local/opt/qt/lib -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/usr/local/opt/python@3.10/bin/python3.10 -DBUILD_TESTS=OFF -DNO_QT_TOOLS=yes
==> cmake --build build
==> Fetching pyside
==> Downloading https://download.qt.io/official_releases/QtForPython/pyside6/PySide6-6.4.0.1-src/pyside-setup-opensource-src-6.4.0.tar.xz
==> Downloading from https://ftp.fau.de/qtproject/official_releases/QtForPython/pyside6/PySide6-6.4.0.1-src/pyside-setup-opensource-src-6.4.0.tar.xz
######################################################################## 100.0%
```

Couldn't brew fetch and install `pyside` binaries instead of having to wait hours till the compilation finishes?

Comment: This might help: https://docs.brew.sh/FAQ#why-do-you-compile-everything

Comment: Is that what you want, in install binares rather than compile?  Or, are you looking for the “why” it does what it does?

Answer (score 1):

Posting this as an answer for future reference. From the [Homebrew Documentation: FAQ (Frequently Asked Questions](https://docs.brew.sh/FAQ#why-do-you-compile-everything) provided by @Martin R in a comment.

> ### Why do you compile everything?
>
> Homebrew provides pre-built binary packages for many formulae. These
> are referred to as [bottles](https://docs.brew.sh/Bottles) and are available at
> https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/packages.
>
> If available, bottled binaries will be used by default except under
> the following conditions:
>
> - The --build-from-source option is invoked.
> - No bottle is available for the machine’s currently running OS version. (Bottles for macOS are generated only for supported macOS
>   versions.)
> - Homebrew is installed to a prefix other than the default (although some bottles support this).
> - Formula options were passed to the install command. For example, brew install  will try to find a bottled binary, but brew
>   install --with-foo  will trigger a source build.
>
> We aim to bottle everything.